# What is dimension of $Z(R)$ as a $k$ vector space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, semi-simple-rings

> Let $k$ be a algebraically closed field and let $R$ be a semi-simple finite dimensional $k$-algebra.
> Show that the number of primitive central idempotents of $R$ is the same as the dim$_k Z(R)$.

I suspect that the center will be spanned by these idempotents, but I'm not sure how to relate them. Please guide me.

Comment: What is the definition of primitive central idempotent elements? Are you allowed to use Artin-Wedderburn theorem? If so, $R$ is isomorphic to the $k$ algebra of direct sum of $n_i$ by $n_i$ matrices with entries in $k$ where $R \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^m R_i$ where $R_i$ is a simple ring. And the dimension of $Z(R)$ is just the sum of $n_i$.

Comment: @monikernemo that dimension is too high. Each simple factor only contributes $1$ additional dimension to the  center.

Comment: ah right, I forgot that the center must be constant diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 2):

By the Artin-Wedderburn theorem, the ring is a unique direct sum of $n$ matrix rings over $k$ (since $k$ is algebraically closed).

Each one has a one has center isomorphic to $k$, and the center of the whole ring is the direct sum of centers of the parts, so the center has dimension $n$ over $k$.

Each centrally primitive idempotent produces an ideal summand which is one of the n simple factors.  So the number of centrally primitive idempotents is equal to n as well.